# C++ an array of objects instantiation (I'm trying to find a compile time solution)

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, I have the following C++ class:

```
struct A {
  A(const int value) {}
};
```

If I want a single object, I can do this:

```
A a = A(3);
```

I would like to construct 10 of these objects, I don't know how to instantiate statically.

```
A a[10]; // This won't compile, as struct A constructor needs an argument
```

I can use a pointer `A *a`, and then create the object one by one, but I am not sure if there is new feature in `C++11` available which allows I can do these in 1 shot statically?

Answer (score 7):

List initialization allows you to write

```
A a[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Each element in the list will be passed to `A`'s constructor.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88c83469196b09dc)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the same parameter for all the instances of `A`, you can use a support function like the following one:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

struct A {
    A(int value): v{value} { }

    template<std::size_t... I>
    static A* create(std::index_sequence<I...>, int val) {
        return new A[sizeof...(I)]{ (I, val)... };
    }

    template<std::size_t N>
    static A* create(int val) {
        return create(std::make_index_sequence<N>(), val);
    }

    int v;
};

int main() {
    A *arr = A::create<10>(42);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) assert(arr[i].v == 42);
    delete[] arr;
}
```

The basic idea is to let it creates a new array of `N` instances of `A` and use the same parameter `val` for all of them during the construction.

**NOTE**

`std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` are part of the game since the revision C++14. If you cannot use them, online you can find a C++11 implementation that should help you to use almost the same code shown above:

Comment: @downvoters For this is a minimal, working solution, a comment for the downvote would be appreciated. It would help understanding what's wrong from your points of view at least... Thanks.